# Integral with an index

Tags: integration

I have an economic problem where it is claimed that the production of final goods is given by the following integral

$$
Y=\int_{i=0}^{i=1}x_idi
$$

where $x_i$ is the production of firms in an intermediate sector. In the intermediate sector there are infinite firms producing the intermediate product $x_i$.
I will appreciate if anyone can help me to understand three things:

1. How do you understand the integral over a subindex?
2. How do you solve this integral?
3. How do you compute $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x_i}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i is in the range [0,1]. Every i, is a firm. This is why there are infinite firms. Every firm i produces $x_i$

Answer (score 0):

From what I know about such models, $x_i$ should be considered as a continuous function of $i$: $x(i)$ that maps $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This means that you have infinitely many firms producing some goods. The integral would be just
$$Y=\int_0^1 x(i)di.$$
However, I do not think that the integral $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x_i}$ makes sense as a variation of $x$ on a zero-measure set does not change the value of the integral.